# ActiveMQ ObjectMessage Security is not working on linux with SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES variable

Tags: java, linux, jms, activemq-classic

As I read from [activemq object message security article](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html), from activemq 5.12.2

> ActiveMQ enforces users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be
>   exchanged using ObjectMessages.

I put `-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"` into env script into ACTIVEMQ_OPTS env variable, as the article said, but the error is still on.

I fix it in windows, but it is not working in linux.

Does any one have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The property that you have there is correct. The source that loads that property is located in:

```
activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java
```

Can you check that you are using the correct version of the ActiveMQ client library - it needs to be greater or equal to 5.12.2 or 5.13.0.

As a wider point, ObjectMessage usage should generally be considered as an anti-pattern when messages are exchanged between systems, as it locks both the producer and consumer code to using the exact same version of the library containing the message payload classes (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html). It is usually preferable to favour text or binary payloads; if you have to serialize objects do so through a mechanism other than Java serialization, such as protocol buffers, which defines a versioned interface contract.